# Connecting to AS400 with ODBC in Excel VBA (ADODB) - Credentials issue

Tags: excel, vba, odbc

I'm trying to create a simple query that will return a single record from an AS400, however I want to avoid having to embed credentials in the connection string, either in the VBA itself or with a user prompt.

I'm used to MS Access, where passthrough queries to the AS400, if they are refused, will prompt for a username/password with the iAccess login prompt. This doesn't happen with the VBA, though, it just returns an error. This is a little inconsistent, sometimes the connection just goes through if I already have on

Is there something I can do in the code to cause the usual prompt to appear on a failed connection?

Code I'm using to test this out is below:

```
Sub ConnTest()

Dim db As New ADODB.Connection
Dim rs As New ADODB.Recordset
Dim conStr As String
Dim qryStr As String
Dim rRng As Range

conStr = "{my connection string}"

qryStr = "{query that returns a single value}"

db.Open conStr
rs.Open qryStr, db

Set rRng = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1")
rRng.CopyFromRecordset rs

End Sub
```

Comment: Is `qryStr` a pass through query or just a standard SQL text?

Comment: @Nathan_Sav Its a passthrough query.

Comment: Is conStr to Access or AS400?

Comment: To the AS400, iSeries Access ODBC Driver.